# How to fix 'java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException' error when I insert data in MySQL?

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Im using preparedStatement, and i have java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException error

```java
query = "INSERT INTO instdb (" +
     "id," +
     "name," +
     "username," +
     "descr," +
     "tel," +
     "vk," +
     "ownerId," +
     "query," +
     "postId," +
     "parametr) VALUES" +
     "(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
stmt.setInt(1, maxid);
stmt.setString(2,user.getFull_name());
stmt.setString(3,username);
stmt.setString(4,caption);
stmt.setString(5,longestTel);
stmt.setString(6,vk);
stmt.setString(7,ownerId);
stmt.setString(8,addons.get(j));
stmt.setString(9,postId);
stmt.setString(10,param);
stmt.executeUpdate(query);
```

And on `stmt.executeUpdate(query);` error

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Before it was another error, but I already fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to put the query in the following method call for prepared statements. You have already added the sql query to the prepared statement.

```
stmt.executeUpdate();
```